# Is there any Ruby Application Server equivalent to JEE's Glassfish or JBoss?

Tags: ruby, application-server

I am wondering if there are Ruby platforms providing bundled services such as Web/Messaging/Workers/Scheduling/...

I am currently using Rails, but I have *also* to manage lifecycle for workers, WebSocket stack & so on.

Any idea? *(I had a look at cerise, which seems to have died meanwhile... :-( )*

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is project called [Torquebox](http://torquebox.org/), which is build upon JBoss AS. It runs Rails/Sinatra (and probably any other Rack application) projects and has integrations for messaging, scheduling and services.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. But this is achievable using any Servlet wrapper like Warbler & co. My question is rather "do we have something providing the services of an application server but full-ruby ?"...